# Class Decorator for Async Function

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-decorators

I hope the title is self-explanatory, here is the code:

```py
class my_class:
    def foo(self,f):
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

inst = my_class()
@inst.foo
async def this():
    print("This is cool")

task = asyncio.create_task(this())
```

As you can see, I am trying to run the function `this()` with the decorator `foo` (from `my_class`).

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<censored>", line 23, in <module>
    task = asyncio.create_task(this())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py", line 360, in create_task
    loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'my_class.foo.<locals>.wrapper' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there. Just replace `asyncio.create_task` with `asyncio.run`.

```py
class my_class:
def foo(self,f):
    async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("inside the wrapper")
        return await f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


inst = my_class()
@inst.foo
async def this():
    print("This is cool")


asyncio.run(this())
# inside the wrapper
# This is cool

# or...
async def main():
    this()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`asyncio.create_task`, creates a task on `asyncio.get_running_loop()`. And it doesn't wait for it to run. It returns a `Task` that can be `await`-ed. Keep it simple for your use-case. :)